# help to install Ubuntu 20.04 without damage data

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

help someone to properly install ubuntu 20.04 next to windows from windows bootloader. I ready to pay a little/
I has disk 1 tera
this is partition
[image]

when I begin installation process
mu USB Ubuntu disk ask me that:[image]

please where I could set up my new Ubuntu that not demage existin data on disk names: succes and Video?
and how to know why in second picture are 145.2 GB - wher this is on 1 st picture? thank you in advance

Comment: You should use Windows to shrink a NTFS partition to make unallocated space for Linux partitions. And reboot to allow it to run chkdsk. You show sda7 as mostly empty, but NTFS. You cannot install Ubuntu to NTFS partition. And cannot make ext4 partition in Windows. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview Be sure to boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI boot mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Another thing you can do is move the sda8 partition to the end of the disk. This allows you to use the 8 GB of unallocated space you have there right now. Copy the data from sda7 to another NTFS-partition (if it is important) and delete the partition. You will end up with 273 GB of unallocated space for your Ubuntu.

Comment: !!!!!! thank you very very much. Because on another computer with the same 1 tera I begin instal and installation USB disk delete all data on this 1 tera disk.